# tuple concurrently updated when creating functions in postgresql / PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql

When initializing my process, it runs the PL/pgSQL statement below creating two functions. However, every time I create multiple processes simultaneously as part of an end-to-end test, parallel execution of this statement leads to a `tuple concurrently updated` error that I can't seem to get around. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  count_rows(schema text, tablename text) returns integer
  AS
  $body$
  DECLARE
    result integer;
    query varchar;
  BEGIN
    query := 'SELECT count(1) FROM "' || schema || '"."' || tablename || '"';
    execute query into result;
    return result;
  END;
  $body$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  delete_if_empty(schema text, tablename text) RETURNS INTEGER
  AS
  $$
  DECLARE
    result integer;
    query varchar;
  BEGIN
    query := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "' || schema || '"."' || tablename || '"';
    execute query into result;
    IF result = 0 THEN
      EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE "' || schema || '"."' || tablename || '" CASCADE;';
      EXECUTE 'NOTIFY "' || schema || '", ''DESTROY_TABLE:' || tablename || ''';';
      RETURN 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN 0;
  END;
  $$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  SELECT version()
```

Comment: This at least explains why it happens (why `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` cannot be run concurrently without the `tuple concurrently updated` error): https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3473.1393693757%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3473.1393693757%40sss.pgh.pa.us), postgres doesn't currently allow you to use `CREATE FUNCTION` concurrently:

> It'd be necessary to add
>   some kind of locking scheme if you want to avoid "tuple concurrently
>   updated" errors.  This is not really any different from the situation
>   where two transactions both want to update the same row in a user table:
>   unless the application takes extra steps to serialize the updates, you're
>   going to get "tuple concurrently updated" errors.
>
> We do have such locking for DDL on tables/indexes, but the theory in the
>   past has been that it's not worth the trouble for objects represented by
>   single catalog rows, such as functions or roles.

A solution to this is to ensure that no two transaction try to do the `CREATE FUNCTION` at the same time.

You can use posgres **advisory locks** for that.

A good introduction to advisory locks can be found here: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-postgresql-advisory-locks-work/

For example, you can use:

```
BEGIN; -- start of transaction

SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(2142616474639426746); -- random 64-bit signed ('bigint') lock number

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction ...

COMMIT;
```

This takes a transaction-level exclusive advisory lock, so that no two concurrent transaction can run create the function at the same time. At the end of the transaction, the lock is automatically released.