# why postgres gives concurrently row updated error when I'm locking the whole table explicitly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, multithreading, asynchronous, io

I have a `nodejs` app that does the following:

```
data = [someObjectWithDate1, someObjectWithDate2, someObjectWithDate3, ....]
//item contains age group
data.forEach(async(item)=>{
    //db connection is already obtained at this point and it allows raw queries
    //typically a knex instance wrapper function/object
    await dbConnection().raw(  
    `
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
      DECLARE
         my_integer integer=${item.age_group};
         my_record record; 
      BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM my_table INTO my_record WHERE age_group=32;
            --some weird calculation but, it's only a sample
            UPDATE my_table SET age_group = my_record.age_group + my_integer 
                  WHERE age_group = my_integer;
      END;
    $$;
    BEGIN;
       LOCK TABLE my_table IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK;
        SELECT * FROM my_function();
    COMMIT;
    `
    )
})
```

now, no matter how many async functions execute parallely, postgres should block concurrent transactions and not give any concurrency issues right? (Albeit hindering performance, which is unnecessary at this point). But, when a large number of array is passed in `data`, I get the following error:

```
tuple concurrently updated {
   "length": 90,
   "name": "error",
"severity": "ERROR",
"code": "XX000",
"file": "heapam.c",
"line": "3888",
"routine": "simple_heap_update",
"stack": "error: \n ..... [ the query above is printed here as well as the following:]-tuple
concurrently updated\n    at Parser.parseErrorMessage 
(/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:357:11)\n    at 
Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol
/src/parser.ts:186:21)\n    at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-
protocol/src/parser.ts:101:30)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)\n    at Socket.emit (domain.js:470:12)\n    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)\n    at 
readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)\n    at 
Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)\n    at 
TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

it's simply not working, what's the reason behind this?

UPDATE: I also wrapped the function call with `advisory locks` as suggested in the comment below, but, it's still giving me the above error when using large enough arrays:

```
BEGIN;    
    SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(2142616474639426746);
    SELECT * FROM my_function();
COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function() ....
```

Comment: So what is the exact error message? I doubt it's `error: ......`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I just did an ellipsis because, the it prints the query that I had in the raw query statement , and something extra, I'll edit avove

Comment: My guess would be that the conflict is over creating `my_function` rather than accessing `my_table`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44101303/1884363
I'd leave an answer, but you're using features I've never used, so I'm unsure.

Comment: @sudo , I've used `advisory locks` as shown in the post you pointed, but, it's still giving me errors, I've edited the question to show how I've done it, am I doing it right? or is there something else I needed to do? It's somehow minimized the amount of conflict I'm getting , but, still doesn't explain why I'm getting it at all

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sudo's comment above, If I moved the statements like this:

```
BEGIN;    
    SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(2142616474639426746);
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function() ....
    --the whole function definition is wrapped by an advisory lock
    SELECT * FROM my_function();
COMMIT;
```

then it seems to avoid the problem, I've used large data(actually faked it with repeated loops through same data). Do note that it might not be the most efficient way to do this sort of thing, but, it works. The problem with the attempt *given in the question* was that the lock was probably only limited to the transaction it was defined in and hence the creation of function was still outside it's scope i.e. not locked, hence the conflict was appearing. But, all seems fine and dandy now.

Comment: @sudo , if you could review the logic I've mentioned, it'd be great for future reference, also if you'd like to add your answer, I'd mark that as accepted. :-)

Comment: This looks right. Only one of these begin...commit statements will run at a time, globally.